# How to connect to Google big query with spark using java locally?

Tags: java, apache-spark, google-bigquery

I am trying to connect to Google big query using spark in java, but I am unable to find accurate documentation for the same.

I tried: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example

and

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-bigquery-connector#compiling-against-the-connector

My code:

```
sparkSession.conf().set("credentialsFile", "/path/OfMyProjectJson.json");
Dataset<Row> dataset = sparkSession.read().format("bigquery").option("table","myProject.myBigQueryDb.myBigQuweryTable")
          .load();
dataset.printSchema();
```

But this is throwing exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:247)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filter(TraversableLike.scala:259)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:614)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:164)
    at com.mySparkConnector.getDataset(BigQueryFetchClass.java:12)


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A project ID is required for this service but could not be determined from the builder or the environment.  Please set a project ID using the builder.
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:142)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.<init>(ServiceOptions.java:285)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions.<init>(BigQueryOptions.java:91)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions.<init>(BigQueryOptions.java:30)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions$Builder.build(BigQueryOptions.java:86)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance(BigQueryOptions.java:159)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider$.$lessinit$greater$default$2(BigQueryRelationProvider.scala:29)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider.<init>(BigQueryRelationProvider.scala:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    ... 15 more
```

My json file contains project_id
I tried searching for possible solutions but am unable to find any, hence please help me with finding a solution to this exception, or else any documentation on how to connect to big query with spark.

Answer (score 2):

I've got exactly the same error with DataProcPySparkOperator operator in the Airflow. The fix was to provide

```
dataproc_pyspark_jars='gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar'
```

instead of

```
dataproc_pyspark_jars='gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest.jar'
```

I guess in your case it should be passed as a command line argument like

```
--jars=gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar
```

Comment: I would add that the problem here might be the scala version (2.11 or 2.12) which depends on your Spark version. For me, I was setting up my AWS EMR with delta and bigquery support. Both work fine now as I use Spark 3.x with Scala 2.12.

Answer (score 0):

Recently a [PR handling this issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-bigquery-connector/pull/33) has been merged to the the spark-bigquery-connector, a new version of the connector will be released soon.

A simple solution for now is to add the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/OfMyProjectJson.json to the spark runtime.

Comment: How should I upload my json credential file and set its path as env variable?

Comment: I assume you have a json file locally. If you don't, you can create one as explained here https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys. Adding it to your environment can be done by adding `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/OfMyProjectJson.json` to your ~/.bashrc if it's your developer machine